# Recyclerview не отображает повторно значения

Tags: android, recyclerview, view

Recyclerview должен отображать повторно заголовок и список чекбоксов. но выводит только один заголовок и один список чекбоксов. не понимаю в чем беда.

```
public class FiltersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<String> genres;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> genreListValues;
    private Example values;
    boolean[] checked;

    private final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
    private final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;

    FiltersAdapter(Context context, Example values, List<String> genres){
        this.context = context;
        this.genres = genres;
        this.values = values;
        checked = new boolean[values.getValues().size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_ITEM1;

        return TYPE_ITEM2;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        if(i == TYPE_ITEM1){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.filter_title_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            return  new FilterTitleViewHolder(v);
        }else if (i == TYPE_ITEM2){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.filter_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new FilterCheckBoxViewHolder(v);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + i + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        genreListValues = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> genreValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> yearsValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> directorsValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int j = 0; j<values.getValues().size(); j++){
            for(int k = 0; k<values.getValues().get(j).getGenre().size(); k++){
                genreValues.add(values.getValues().get(j).getGenre().get(k));
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j<values.getValues().size(); j++){
            yearsValues.add(values.getValues().get(j).getYear());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j<values.getValues().size(); j++){
            directorsValues.add(values.getValues().get(i).getDirector());
        }

        genreListValues.add(genreValues);
        genreListValues.add(yearsValues);
        genreListValues.add(directorsValues);

        if(viewHolder instanceof FilterTitleViewHolder){
            ((FilterTitleViewHolder) viewHolder).title.setText(genres.get(i));
        }else if(viewHolder instanceof FilterCheckBoxViewHolder){
            for(int j = 0; j<genreListValues.size(); j++){
                ((FilterCheckBoxViewHolder) viewHolder).cbFilter.setText(genreListValues.get(j).get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.getValues().size();
    }


    public static class FilterCheckBoxViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CheckBox cbFilter;

        public FilterCheckBoxViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cbFilter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_filter);
        }
    }

    public static class FilterTitleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;

        public FilterTitleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы меня извините конечно, но по всему видно, что вы взялись за задачу, которую не сможете решить. То, что вы сейчас делаете - это полный треш. По хорошему вам нужно сесть и нарабатывать теорию, исследуя правильные решения, почитать литературу, а не бросаться на эту "амбразуру" с околонулевыми знаниями по предмету.  В частности, в списках никаких циклов быть не может, каким образом вы собираетесь потом получать результаты выбора?

Comment: Для правильного решения вам нужно работать с базой данных, в которой будет хранится вся информация по, видимо, фильмам. Из этой базы вычитывать значения для заполнения пунктов фильтра, соответственно потом по ним составлять запрос на выборку из базы. Чтобы решить вашу проблему, требуется комплексный подход, сравнимый с разработкой небольшого приложения и формат этого ресурса не предназначен для таких решений. Рекомендую вам найти опенсорное приложение с аналогичным функционалом (какие есть на гитхабе) хорошенько изучить его и сюда уже обращаться по конкретным локальным проблемам